# Check if unique combinations exist in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to add a constraint when creating a table, *Order*, such that the unique combination of fields exist within another table.

```
Table: Product
productId PRIMARY KEY
productNumber
```

and,

```
Table: Order
clientId FOREIGN KEY
productId FOREIGN KEY
productNumber
dateBorrowed
dateReturned
```

I have two tables *Product* and *Order*. The *productId* and *productNumber* create a unique combination to specify a product as multiple versions of the same product may exist.
When entering values into the *Order* table the unique combination of *productId* and *productNumber* must exist within the *Product* table, duplicates are allowed as items can be returned and borrowed again at a later date.
I'm not sure how I would go about coding the constraint when creating the *Order* table, hope that all made sense.

Example Data:
Product

| ProductId | ProductNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 2 |
| 675 | 1 |

Table

| clientId | productId | productNumber | dateBorrowed | dateReturned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 123 | 1 | 1979 | 1989 |
| 10 | 123 | 1 | 1990 | 2000 |
| 12 | 675 | 1 | 2022 | 2022 |
| 07 | 123 | 2 | 1982 | 2022 |

Comment: `productId PRIMARY KEY` means that `productId` is unique in the table `Product` so how is it possible that *multiple versions of the same product may exist*?

Comment: @forpas The productId refers to the product in general. So for example, a Library. They have multiple copies of the exact same book. The book would be the productId whilst the individual copies would be the productNumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *unique combination of fields* you describe is in fact the primary key :

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
    productId INTEGER,
    productNumber INTEGER,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (productId, productNumber)
);
```

You can reference it in the `Order` table :

```
CREATE TABLE "Order"(
    ...
    productId INTEGER,
    productNumber INTEGER,
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY(productId, productNumber) REFERENCES Product(productId, productNumber)
);
```

Please note the Order table name must be quoted, `ORDER` is a SQLite keyword.
Also foreign keys must be enabled :

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```